# Moving my robot from ROS and getting sensor information back

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm a bit stuck with the whole Gazebo-ROS integration.

I went through basic Gazebo tutorials, created a small two-wheeled robot with a laser (simple SDF file and world file).
Now I want to move it (apply force to both wheels) and get laser output using ROS.
I'm not even sure what has to be done next. Gazebo model plugin that reads move commands from ROS topics and publishes laser output to another topic? Or is there something ready-to-use?

Jack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6336/moving-my-robot-from-ros-and-getting-sensor-information-back./) by [jnikodem](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/820/jnikodem/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there is a list of available plugins in the wiki:

[`ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins`](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins)

there you might find the plugins you are looking for...

I think the **(GPU)Laser** and **Differential Drive** could do the job(i never used the second one...)

btw for processing sensor information it would be more useful to write a sensor plugin instead of a model plugin. The rest of your approach seems to be right if you decide to implement this yourself.

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2014-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0